# Is it possible to see and manage Azure Spatial Anchors online?

Tags: azure, azure-spatial-anchors

Is it possible to see the list of the created Azure Spatial Anchors, and delete the useless ones? I know that we can set the expire day for anchors but in my case we 'd need to create permanent anchors but we want to be able to delete them when they are not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of June 2020, neither the SDK nor the Azure Portal provide a way to enumerate the anchors that you have created in the system. [This feature is in the roadmap](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919252-azure-spatial-anchors/suggestions/37107037-show-a-list-of-all-the-created-anchors-in-a-webpag) but it’s not available yet. Today you need to managed the list externally in your own storage.

Comment: the link is broken. Is it still on the roadmap?