# How to link Azure Spatial Anchor to Cosmos DB in Android Studio Java

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-spatial-anchors

I having a hard time understanding the documentation provided.
Right now, I am able to create an anchor and the created anchor is shown in my Azure Spatial Anchors account in the Azure Portal.  But, I don't see any details about the anchor I created.

I'm planing to link the created anchors to a Cosmos DB document or some other method that I can use to get the anchor data.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Ly Wee, can you share snippet of what you have done so far?

Comment: If your question is about looking at anchor details in the Azure Portal, see [Is it possible to see and manage Azure Spatial Anchors online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505446/is-it-possible-to-see-and-manage-azure-spatial-anchors-online) (Briefly, as of June 2020, not yet.) For saving anchor metadata in your own database, see the [Sharing Azure Spatial Anchors across sessions and devices with an Azure Cosmos DB back end](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-use-cosmos-db-to-store-anchors#deploy-the-sharing-anchors-service) tutorial.

Comment: thank you @artfulbeest for the reply.  I managed to link them to cosmosdb.  I just realize that needed the app service to link them.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To save additional metadata about an anchor, you can create an entry for it in a database of your own design. You can model this however makes sense for your application.

The [Sharing Azure Spatial Anchors across sessions and devices with an Azure Cosmos DB back end tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-use-cosmos-db-to-store-anchors#deploy-the-sharing-anchors-service) is a simple example that shows how to share just the anchor id among devices.